# Subquery Returned More Than one Error

Tags: sql-server, date, datetime, subquery

**I need to pull Data for the dates which I have Declared in The sample Table but somehow i get the error :**
***Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.***

is there any way i can stop this from Happening and allow my query to pull data from the List of dates.

Here is my query  and thanks in advance :)

```
Declare @Sample_Alankar Table
(
 --Author_id int,
 Sent_date Datetime,
 Fixed_Date datetime
)
Declare @StartDate DateTime
Declare @EndDate DateTime
Declare @NumOfDays Int

Set @NumOfDays = 4 
Set @StartDate = '5/1/2013'
Set @EndDate =  '12/31/2013'

insert @Sample_Alankar values 
('11/5/2013','11/13/2013'),
('11/5/2013','11/13/2013'),
('11/4/2013','11/13/2013'),
('9/18/2013','9/25/2013'),
('11/4/2013','11/13/2013'),
('9/3/2013','9/10/2013'),
('11/5/2013','11/6/2013'),
('11/4/2013','11/12/2013'),
('11/4/2013','11/12/2013'),
('11/4/2013','11/12/2013')

;With Cte_Fixed_Date as 
(Select  Distinct (Q.Topic_ID) , First_Start_date , QR.Author_ID
from Question Q 
Left Join QuestionResponse QR  on Q.Topic_ID = QR.Topic_ID 
Left Join exptblFeedback EF with (nolock) on Q.Topic_ID = EF.Topic_ID
Left Join DWStar.DW03.factFeedback FB with (nolock) on Q.Topic_ID = FB.TopicID
Join Forum FO with (nolock) on FO.Forum_ID = Q.Forum_ID
Join exptblCategory C with (nolock) on C.Cat_ID = FO.Cat_ID
inner join CategoryExpert CE WITH (NOLOCK) on QR.Author_ID = CE.Author_ID and Fo.Forum_ID = CE.Forum_ID and IsReject = 0
where 
1 = 1 
and First_Start_date between @StartDate and @EndDate
and Q.Author_ID <> Qr.Author_ID 
and Q.culture in('en-US')
and C.Cat_name <> 'Fling'
and First_Start_date between (Select Fixed_Date From @Sample_Alankar) and DATEADD(WEEK,@NumOfDays*(1),(Select Fixed_Date From @Sample_Alankar))
group by Q.Topic_ID, First_Start_date, QR.Author_ID
)
select * from Cte_Fixed_Date
```

Comment: Did you look at any of the many similar questions about this error?

Comment: Your problem is with `(Select Fixed_Date From @Sample_Alankar)`. `@Sample_Alankar` has multiple rows. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to Pick data from the declared date ranges all at once without having to to do it everytime for each row in @sample_alankar

Comment: Please don't tag SQL Server questions with [tag:mysql]. MySQL is a platform, not a catch-all for "my sql query"...

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag because the syntax is clearly SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this as a subquery, then you want to replace:

```
and First_Start_date between (Select Fixed_Date From @Sample_Alankar) and DATEADD(WEEK,@NumOfDays*(1),(Select Fixed_Date From @Sample_Alankar))
```

with something like this:

```
and exists (select 1
            from @Sample_Alankar sa
            where First_Start_date between sa.Send_Date and sa.Fixed_Date
           )
```

However, most people would just do the filtering as a join condition:

```
join
 @Sample_Alankar sa
on First_Start_date between sa.Send_Date and sa.Fixed_Date
```